# How to index sequences of floats? (for euclidean distance)

Tags: python, pattern-matching, sequence, cluster-analysis, data-mining

UPDATE 1: this is not about simple sorting of lists of floats but rather a way to index the lists of floats to later be able to quickly find the ones with the nearest euclidean distances to a sample one.

UPDATE 2: It's fine if it's a different method than just a float index. The main target is to find similar (short euclidean distance) sequences quickly without having to read the whole, or much of, the sequences database.

Perhaps calculating the average is enough, but what I'm looking for is a float number that can be descriptive of the sequence it represents.

For instance, these sequences of floats:

```
sequence[0] = [0.42, 0.81, 0.33, 0.19, 0.56]
sequence[1] = [0.72, 0.93, 0.14, 0.92, 0.88]

average[0] = 0.462
average[1] = 0.718
```

The idea is to sort the sequences by this "indexing float" (in the example: the average) so when another sequence is compared with the list of sequences to find similar ones it can start comparing (euclidean distance) from the nearest "indexing float" and move the pointer up and down from that point in the array.

It would be a float number that would allow to get "near" those sequences that have smaller euclidean distances to the sample sequence being searched.

Comment: The language: Python.

Comment: Do you need to only use a single float for your index, or can you use a more complicated data structure? Basically, in a high dimensional space like yours, a single float is not going to fare well. You might do better using the euclidean norm (square root of the sum of the squares of the elements), which will group elements of similar magnitude together, but probably won't help too much when data gets large.

If the number of sequences is very large, you'll want to use a data structure like a kd-tree (not so hard to write) to quickly find neighbors.

Comment: It's fine if it's more complex. The target is to quickly find sequences in large lists without having to read the whole (or too much) of the database.

Comment: @Anna, would a kd-tree allow to find sequences within a distance threshold? (euclidean distance). So besides the nearest neighbor, getting all sequences in a certain range of distances up to a threshold.

Answer (score 0):

f.e. in C# you can use a sorted dictionary 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx

basically you can implement the data structure on your own in every language.

Comment: if that is a simple sort of lists of floats, this is different. The idea is to index the sequences for bringing near in the list those with similar euclidean distance. It would be a first step, and then, when searching for a sequence, start searching on those with a similar index first thus finding similar sequences quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right.

But it sounds as if your are looking for R-tree, R*-tree, kd-tree, quadtree type of data structures? I.e. index structures to search for nearest neighbors?

Comment: Possibly. The idea is to index sequences to quickly find near neighbors, i.e. shortest euclidean distance. Although not only the nearest, but rather several near ones with a threshold.

Comment: Yes, these data structures can accelerate also kNN search.